# I consider it possible to reposition orbitals without reboost and no thrusters I would like to discuss this Idea with someone?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, design-alternative

Ok I'm going to label this idea "Skiing in Space" as that analogy is possible the simplest to grasp the concept.

When a person moves on skis he/she has to shift body weight to the relevant side to lift the other. Simple enough but what if we could attach rotatable extendable tanks around an orbital and pump the mass from one location to another would we be able to reposition the centre mass much the same way, Like moving a needle on a record to another position. My calculations say this should be possible and Id like to bounce the idea to all of these readers to see what you think!

Comment: The accepted answer there doesn't appear to be entirely reliable.

Comment: Im sorry link to the question ?

Comment: I cannot find any duplication and the Idea although a simple one and maybe thought about by another if you can point me to the location of this so called duplicate ?

Comment: The center of mass would stay in the same spot relatively to the body you are orbiting so the orbit wouldn't change. You would just move your craft around the com but the com would stay in the same spot.